# Where to check if something was changed on Django Admin

Tags: python, django-admin, django-rest-framework

I have a Model on Django-rest-framework, and I need to check every time a field on that Model was updated in the Django-Admin in order to do a update in another model.

How and where can I check it?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you be using Django Signals or other technologies to make the updates automatically? It does not seem to be a very good idea to manually update models each time somebody makes an API call.

Comment: Model A is updated only by Django Admin. When for example name of Model A is updated on Django Admin, I need to make a update on Model B. So I only need to know when an update was made to made my changes, @ssice

Comment: Anyway, why not make it automatically? Besides, you should add all that information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

@ssice is right you can utilise [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save), along with something like [django-dirtyfields](https://github.com/romgar/django-dirtyfields).

Or

If it's a one time thing, you can roll your own dirty field checker for that model by overriding model's `__init__()` and `save()` methods. Something like this (of course it can be much more complex depending on your requirements):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YOUR_MODEL, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # SAVE THE INITIAL VALUE
    self.__original_value = self.value_you_want_to_track

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Compare the initial value with the current value
    if self.__original_value != self.value_you_want_to_track:
         # DO SOMETHING, MAYBE TRIGGER SIGNAL
    super(YOUR_MODEL, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    # Finally update the initial value after the save complete
    self.__original_value = self.value_you_want_to_track
```

---

**CAUTION**

These would NOT work if you use model `update()`, as it does not trigger django's `save()` or related signals. But you said you want to track the changes made from the admin site, so I'm assuming this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to watch changes in Django Admin change form, you can hook the `save_model()` method of your ModelAdmin.

```
class YourAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        # do what you have to do here
```

You may also want to enclose this in a transaction to ensure the model is not saved if the other operation failed.

```
class YourAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    @transaction.atomic
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        # do what you have to do here
```